# One project with multiple angular app architecture

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven

I need to develop a new project that will contain several AngularJS application and I have a questions about the project architecture.

The solution will behave 5 webapp (for the moment) and the customer can choose the modules he wishes. These applications will be available only on its networks.

I thought two solution

- First solution: develop 5 war (easy to deploy war according customer needs)
- Second solution: make a unique war (and configure in database which applications will be available)

Regarding the first solution:

I wanted to create a maven module for each webapp + a "core" module that will be included in each webapp module and will contain spring configuration (which is 95% identical between each webapp), entities, dao and some shared services. Do you see any problems to proceed this way?

Concerning the second solution

In fact I do not even know how to do it yet but I think it's doable (maybe with a http filter ?)

So what is the best solution knowing I privilege maintainability over performance?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you may meed is a project with front-end layer, service layer and DAO layer.

Prepare three of them as separate maven projects and then add them as maven dependencies or create an appropriate package structure in a single project.

In front-end, instead of using 5 different projects you can use a single project with a switching page. from the switching page you can direct requests to corresponding app you want with the aid of spring configured mvc-dispatcher.

folder structure for front-end in my suggestion would be looks like as in below,

```
-webapp 
 |_web-inf
  |_pages
   |_app
    |_project A
    |_project B
     |_scripts
      |_projects B's sub module A
      |_projects B's sub module B
       |_controllers
       |_factories
       |_model
       |_services
       |_views
      |_projects B's sub module C
      |_projects B's sub module D
      |_projects B's sub module E
    |_project C
    |_project D
    |_project E
```

You can map your resources in you application using mvc-dispatcher as below,

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/projectA/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/app/projectA/scripts/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/projectB/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/app/projectB/scripts/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/projectC/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/app/projectC/scripts/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/projectD/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/app/projectD/scripts/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/projectE/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/app/projectE/scripts/"/>
```

Hope this would be helpful

Comment: So according to your solution, I must make a single war ?

Comment: It depends on how you are going to separate your project. suppose you're going to create Frond-end, Services/controllers and DAO separately. Then you might need two war files(fron-end and services/controllers. DAO can be add as a maven dependency of Service/Controller) If you prefer all client, and server side implementations in a same project, then obviously you need only war file. But thinking about extensibility it is always better to separate front-end and back-end. sorry for replying late :)